# Drain auger broke off and fell down the kitchen sink drain

Tags: plumbing, drain, pipe

My kitchen sink was clogged, so I used my 7m drum drain auger. I managed to unblock the pipe, but when I tried to remove the auger from it, the snake broke off the drum and fell deep down the drain so I can not get to it.

Should I leave it be since the sink drains well or do you recommend I call a plumber to try to get the snake out of the pipes?

Comment: There are 50$ 4' inspection cameras that are perfect for figuring out where it is.

Comment: I'm trying not to suggest using another drain auger to retrieve it... Would the inspection camera count as a drain _augur_?

Comment: Is it possible to use another snake to go down and hook the loose end?

Answer (score 4):

The snake in the drain is going to collect stuff and build up another clog over time.  So yes, I'd see if I could remove it.  You might try taking the trap apart and see if you can access it here.  Otherwise, you may need to get a plumber who can retrieve it.

Comment: The snake is down lower than the trap, looks like it went all the way to the plumbings in the basement.

Comment: If there is a cleanout in the basement, that might be a good place to look.  I think it's unlikely it went all the way to the sewer though.  So it's going to be an issue sooner or later.